# Instanceof в js

Tags: javascript

Можете объяснить мне разницу между

```
function A() {}

A.prototype = {};

var a = new A();

alert( a instanceof A ); // true
```

и

```
function A() {}

var a = new A();

A.prototype = {};

alert( a instanceof A); // false
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`instanceof` проверяет, что хотя бы один из `__proto__` в цепочке прототипов объекта совпадает с `prototype` функции. В первом случае первый же совпадёт (так работает `new`), а во втором - нет, поскольку у объекта осталась ссылка на тот объект, который был до присваивания.

```js
function A() {}
A.prototype = {};
var a = new A();

console.log(a instanceof A);
console.log(a.__proto__ === A.prototype);
```

```js
function A() {}
var a = new A();
A.prototype = {};

console.log(a instanceof A);
console.log(a.__proto__ === A.prototype);
console.log(a.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype);
console.log(a.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__);
```

Comment: ну или можно переопределить _Symbol.hasInstance_ и тогда instanceof Будет немного по другому работать :-D

Comment: @Grundy, да здравствует множественное наследование?